# TYPO3 V9: Site configuration with absolute paths?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I'd like to configure my site similar to `config.absRefPrefix` behaviour in former TYPO3 versions.

Before it was like all links on a webpage had an absolute path when configured with `config.absRefPrefix = https://www.example.com/`. Now with the new site configuration module only the Typoscript generated links in the header and at the footer of the page have absolute paths. The links in the navi and in the content section are always relative.

Does anybody know how to configure the site to have the same behaviour as before in older TYPO3 versions?

Answer (score 3):

If you want absolute URLs in TYPO3 9 or 10, one way could be the new "absolute" attribute for the typolink fluid ViewHelper:

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Functions/Typolink.html#forceabsoluteurl

I have tested this quickly on my website, works great for my logo.

For the Navigation: If you use the TYPO3 MenuProcessor and fluid to create your Menu, you can also work with the absolute="true" attribute. I also tested this, works fine.

For the content elements, these settings work for me on a 9.5.11 and even version 10:

```
// parseFunc
lib.parseFunc.tags.a.typolink.forceAbsoluteUrl = 1
lib.parseFunc.tags.link.typolink.forceAbsoluteUrl = 1
lib.parseFunc.tags.a.typolink.forceAbsoluteUrl.scheme = https
lib.parseFunc.tags.link.typolink.forceAbsoluteUrl.scheme = https

// parseFunc_RTE
lib.parseFunc_RTE.tags.a.typolink.forceAbsoluteUrl = 1
lib.parseFunc_RTE.tags.link.typolink.forceAbsoluteUrl = 1
lib.parseFunc_RTE.tags.a.typolink.forceAbsoluteUrl.scheme = https
lib.parseFunc_RTE.tags.link.typolink.forceAbsoluteUrl.scheme = https
```

I tested everything and have a complete "absolute URL website" here right now.

Comment: Is there any way to apply these settings above only in context of "FluidEmail"?